# Rails default maximum function to zero if there is no value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I have `= trips.maximum(:maximum_speed_mph).round(0).to_s` default to zero if there is no value?

I was able to do it with this `= number_with_precision(trips.average(:average_speed_mpg), :precision=>0) || 0`

The same does not work for `= trips.maximum(:maximum_speed_mph).round(0).to_s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(trips.maximum(:maximum_speed_mph) || 0).round(0).to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

since `nil.to_i == 0` you can do:

```
max = trips.maximum(:maximum_speed_mph).to_i
```

and then convert it to string `max.to_s`

This is interesting if you want to assign a value automatically to your next record. e.g.

```
self.maximum_speed_mph = Trip.maximum_speed_mph.to_i + 1
```